# .htaccess redirect/rewrite rule with ?lang

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect one address with URL parameter to clean URL.

*www.domain.com/?lang=de*

to

*www.domain.com/de*

I know there are many tutorials, but all of them work with wildcard redirect. I just need the rule for just *?lang=de* redirect. Not for *?lang=en* nor for */something/?lang=de*.

I've tried this without success:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+([^?]+?)(?:.php)?\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Any idea, please?

Comment: Does **domain.com/de** exist on your server?

Comment: Sure, it is Drupal powered website and I need redirect a few URLs from the old website that was running on the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?lang=de\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/de? [L,R]
```